# Xamarin Windowservice and Displaymetrics, cant find SystemService

Tags: android, xamarin, android-context

When i try to look through the classes in the Android.Content.Context class, it doesn't show any SystemService, which i need for getting the width and height of the current screen.

```
IWindowManager windowManager = Context. 
(Context.WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager>();

windowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(metrics);

Console.WriteLine("Test: " + metrics.HeightPixels + 
metrics.WidthPixels);
```

the Context gives me alot of different services, but no SystemService, and without this i cant get any further.

Edit 1:

```
 IWindowManager windowManager = CarouselPage.GetSystemService();
```

This just doesnt work, my context doesnt know systemservice nor windowservice

Comment: And what is wrong with `GetMetrics` and the resulting object properties? SystemService? Use a context and call `GetSystemService` with a service name you wish to get. Also there is zero reasons to use JavaCast in your example.

Comment: Then i might not have fully understood this, i am just trying to get height and width of the current users screen. The problem is that i cant use WindowManager only IWindowManager and therefore i am forced to javacast from context to get some sort of object. Correct me if im wrong

Comment: You have a context, so `someContext.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(metrics);`

Comment: my context doesn't allow me to access windowmanager...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> my context doesnt know systemservice nor windowservice

The context that you have is associated to the `View` that you have and thus it has a context and that context will be the hosting Activity.

So cast that context to an Activity:

```
var metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
(someView.Context as Activity)?.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(metrics);
```

System service example:

```
var usbService = (someView.Context as Activity).GetSystemService(UsbService) as UsbManager;
```

Also the containing instance where you are writing this class code would assumably be an Activity and thus you can use **`this`** as the object reference (`this.WindowManager.~~~`)

Comment: (CarouselPageDayView.Context as Activity)

both context and activity raises an error.

Comment: this. doesnt even give me the chance to get a context, only bindingcontext

Comment: @Gustavbang "bindingcontext" ? Are you coding within a `Xamarin.Android` project or a NetStd/PCL Forms' based project?

Comment: I am in a .net project

Comment: @Gustavbang You would need to use a Dependency service to access the Android APIs (or a Xamarin.Android application or library project)

Comment: I just managed to get width with Application.Current.MainPage.Width. seems like i've been searching the wrong forums, thanks for the heads up :)